# $t$ is free for $v$ in $A$

Tags: logic, terminology

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the expression "$t$ is free for $v$ in $A$".

Consider this special case: suppose that $A$ is a wff in which there is no free occurrence of the variable $v.$ Then for any term $t,$ is it correct to say that "$t$ is free for $v$ in $A$" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> suppose that $A$ is a wff in which there is no free occurrence of the variable $v.$ Then for any term $t,$ is it correct to say that "$t$ is free for $v$ in $A$" ?

In this case, there is no free occurrence of $v,$ so replacing every free occurrence of $v$ in $A$ with $t$ means not doing anything, which does not cause any variable in $t$ to become bound; therefore, $t$ is said to be freely substitutable for $v$ in $A,$ that is, “$t$ is free for $v$ in $A$”.